# Convert PostScript to PDF

Tags: command-line, pdf, conversion, postscript

I have multiple postscript files that I'd like to convert to PDF using a script. I'm not looking for script assistance, but rather assistance with what program would/could I use to make the conversion via command line?

Comment: [`ps2pdf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ps2pdf.1)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
ps2pdf file.ps
```

It converts `file.ps` to `file.pdf`

More information about ps2pdf: https://www.ps2pdf.com/

Comment: I don't find a ps2pdf package, is there a package in 16.04 for this program?